# Share Gamepad over Network

Tags: networking, usb, remote-desktop

I'm trying to use my laptop as a USB Receiver for a VM on my server. I have found a few USB Sharing programs, VirtualHere USB looked the most promising, but it seems my Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver and/or Gamepad don't show up as USB Devices and can't be shared. I also tried sharing over RDP, but I guess they aren't PnP devices.

Any suggestions? I will/would also like to share BT Wiimotes over the Network if you have any ideas, but that might be a separate question also might not be possible, I didn't see many results in google.

**Goal: Plug in Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver and connect Xbox 360 Controller to laptop, which passes input to a VM** over some form of connection, be it RDP, TeamViewer, non desktop sharing software etc.

Comment: Update: I'm fairly certain I got VirtualHere USB Server to work for this purpose and it was free for 1 device at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was already trying to do this, but apparently its much more difficult in Windows 10 (Got to love "updates")...

Anyway, what I ended up using since its free (There are probably better alternatives that are paid like Flixehub) is using RemoteFX USB Redirection over Windows RDP.

To enable in windows 10:

Do on both Physical Windows Machine and Remote Host

All Edits are under the following:

```
Computer Configuration \ Administrative Templates \ Windows Components \ Remote Desktop Services \ >>
```

GPEdits:

```
Remote Desktop Connection Client \ RemoteFX USB Device Redirection \ All RDP Redirection (Enable)

Remote Desktop Session Host \ Remote Session Environment \ RemoteFX for Windows Server 2008 R2 \ Configure RemoteFX (Enable)

Remote Desktop Session Host \ Connections \ Allow users to connect remotely using Remote Desktop Services (Enable)

Remote Desktop Session Host \ Device and Resource Redirection\ Do not allow supported Plug and Play device redirection (Disable) 

gpupdate /force in elevated CMD Prompt and reboot
```

Source: >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33719489/how-to-enable-usb-redirection-in-windows-10/46628854#46628854

Note: This also enabled me to share my BT, but I didn't test it yet

Using the Feautre in RDP:

Open RDP >> Show Options >> Local Resources >> More >> Other Supported RemoteFX USB Devices >> (Enable Device to share)

[image]

Then Connect and go under "Devices and Printers", it should be listed, perhaps have to install drivers.

Comment: While this works for sharing Gamepad over LAN, turns out RDP won't let me launch DirectX Games :'(, so I am doing RetroArch + Ice + Steamlink since my gateway is by the TV in the other room. https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/wiki/retroarch-with-steam-using-ice-18055176.html